# Реализовать связанный select опций

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

На входе имеется строка типа:

```
processor_0_i3/chastota_0_1,5/ram_0_8/os_0_Windows/count_0_12/processor_1_i5/chastota_1_2,7/ram_1_16/os_1_Windows/count_1_10/processor_2_i3/chastota_2_1,5/ram_2_32/os_2_Linux/count_2_10
```

В ней записаны несколько опций одного товара.

Дальше строка перерабатывается в массив подобного типа:

```
Array
(
   [processor] => Array
       (
           [0] => i3
           [1] => i5
       )

   [chastota] => Array
       (
           [0] => 1,5
           [1] => 2,7
       )

   [ram] => Array
       (
           [0] => 8
           [1] => 16
           [2] => 32
       )

   [os] => Array
       (
           [0] => Windows
           [1] => Linux
       )

   [count] => Array
       (
           [0] => 12
           [1] => 10
       )

)
```

Из массива получаем селекты: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь самое интересное: В полученных комбинациях селектов есть существующие комбинации опций, но есть и не существующие. На данном этапе, чтобы ограничить выбор неверных комбинаций, после каждого `change` селекта, на сервер отправляется полученная комбинация, и сравнивается и существующими. Но это не совсем правильно, к тому же, неверные комбинации в селектах могут формироваться много раз подряд. В идеале, активность последних селектов должна формироваться в зависимости от первого выбранного. Допустим, при выбранном в первом селекте `processor i3`, в последующих активными должны быть только те опции, которые состоят в комбинациях с первой выбранной опцией. Как это реализовать?

Comment: И почему, по Вашему, не правильно после события change отправлять информацию на сервер?

Comment: @XelaNimed, во-первых, лучше избегать лишний раз обращение к базе. Во-вторых, как это описано ниже, при подборе селектов может раз 10 подряд сформироваться комбинация опций, которой нет, и выбор опций превращается в утомительное казино.

Comment: Лишний раз конечно не нужно обращаться к БД, но если уже полученные данные кешировать на стороне клиента, то лишних обращений к БД не будет и не нужно будет в самом начале загружать все данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выполнения такой задачи, нужно всё таки изначально с сервера передавать массив всех версий продукта, а не только уникальных значений для полей. Что-то похожее на это:

```
<?php

// Исходная строка с характеристиками одного товара.
$product = 'processor_0_i3/chastota_0_1,5/ram_0_8/os_0_Windows/count_0_12/processor_1_i5/chastota_1_2,7/ram_1_16/os_1_Windows/count_1_10/processor_2_i3/chastota_2_1,5/ram_2_32/os_2_Linux/count_2_10';

// Сюда будем записывать версии товара.
$versions = [];

// Также сложим общее количество версий.
$count = 0;

// Создадим предварительно массив, разбив строку. Разделитель - `/`.
$array = explode('/', $product);

foreach ($array as $params) {
    // В данном примере проигнориваны проверки.
    // Опять разбиваем строку, чтобы выделить каждую характеристику.
    // Разделитель - `_`, количество - три.
    [$property, $index, $value] = explode('_', $params, 3);

    // Записываем версию товара.
    $versions[$index][$property] = $value;

    // Если характеристика == `count`,
    // то складываем в общее количество.
    if ('count' === $property) $count += (int) $value;
}

// Debug.
// Характеристики: процессоры, частоты, планки, оси. Уникальные значения.
// $processors = array_keys(array_column($versions, 'processor', 'processor'));
// $frequencies = array_keys(array_column($versions, 'chastota', 'chastota'));
// $memories = array_keys(array_column($versions, 'ram', 'ram'));
// $oses = array_keys(array_column($versions, 'os', 'os'));
// print_r(compact('versions', 'count', 'processors', 'frequencies', 'memories', 'oses'));
```

И основываясь на этот массив версий, и прибегая к функциям по работе с массивами [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) динамически перестраивать выпадающие списки. Как один из вариантов:

```js
// Данные для работы с `javascript` должны быть в `json` формате.
// const VERSIONS = <?= json_encode($versions) ?>;

// Массив версий товара.
const VERSIONS = [{
  "processor": "i3",
  "chastota": "1,5",
  "ram": "8",
  "os": "Windows",
  "count": "12"
}, {
  "processor": "i5",
  "chastota": "2,7",
  "ram": "16",
  "os": "Windows",
  "count": "10"
}, {
  "processor": "i3",
  "chastota": "1,5",
  "ram": "32",
  "os": "Linux",
  "count": "10"
}]

// `NodeList` из выпадающих списков.
const SELECTORS = document.querySelectorAll('select.linked__data')
// Чтобы не нагружать постоянными пересчетами.
const ARRAY_FROM_SELECTORS = Array.from(SELECTORS)
// Поле вывода количества отфильтрованных версий товара.
const SPAN_COUNT = document.getElementById('count')
// Элемент для вывода отфильтрованных версий товара.
const LIST_RESULT = document.getElementById('result')

// Формирование запроса для выбранных значений всех `select`.
// Пустые значения игнорируются.
function selectedQuery(currentIndex) {
  let search = {}

  ARRAY_FROM_SELECTORS.map(function(select, index) {
    // Сбрасываем `value` если index больше текущего.
    if (index > currentIndex) select.value = ''

    // Если в списке выбран пункт, добавляем в запрос.
    if (!!select.value) search[select.name] = select.value
  })

  return search
}

// Массив отфильтрованных объектов, основанных на
// индексе текущего выбранного выпадающего списка
// и сформированного запроса.
function getFiltered(currentIndex) {
  let query = selectedQuery(currentIndex)
  let queryKeys = Object.keys(query)

  return VERSIONS
    .filter(version => queryKeys
      .every(prop => version[prop] == query[prop])
    )
}

// Построение таблицы.
function renderTable(filtered) {
  // Debug.
  // console.clear()
  // console.table(filtered)

  // Очистим форму вывода.
  LIST_RESULT.innerHTML = ''

  // Пройдемся по отфильтрованным версиям.
  filtered.map(function(item) {
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.append(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(item)))
    LIST_RESULT.appendChild(li)
  })
}

// Отрисовка доступного количества.
function renderCount(filtered) {
  SPAN_COUNT.innerText = filtered
    .map(item => item.count)
    .reduce((total, current) => parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(current))
}

// Перестроение выпадающих списков.
function renderSelecotrs(filtered, currentIndex = 0) {
  // По отфильтрованным данным формируем доступные выпадающие списки.
  // Для текущего списка ничего не меняем, поэтому currentIndex + 1,
  // то есть начинаем формирование только со следующего.
  for (let i = currentIndex + 1; i < SELECTORS.length; i++) {
    let name = SELECTORS[i].name

    // Получим список всех возможных уникальных значений для текущего списка.
    let unique = [...new Set(filtered.map(item => item[name]))]

    Array.from(SELECTORS[i])
      .map(option => {
        // Предварительно скроем все элементы в списке.
        option.hidden = 'hidden'
        // Если элемент списка не имеет `value`
        // или `value` находится в списке уникальных.
        // то покажем его.
        if ('' == option.value || unique.includes(option.value)) {
          option.hidden = ''
        }
      })
  }
}

// Функция фильтрации.
function filterList(event = null, currentIndex = 0) {
  // Получаем отфильтрованные данные.
  let filtered = getFiltered(currentIndex)

  // Построим список отфильтрованных версий.
  renderTable(filtered)

  // Обновим количество.
  renderCount(filtered)

  // Обновим выпадающие списки.
  renderSelecotrs(filtered, currentIndex)
}

// Регистрируем обработчика события для каждого выпадающего списка.
ARRAY_FROM_SELECTORS
  .map(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('input', (event) => filterList(event, index))
  })

// Инициируем запуск фильтрации.
filterList()
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

.form-group {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>processor</label>
    <select name="processor" class="form-control linked__data">
      <option value="i3" selected>i3</option>
      <option value="i5">i5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>chastota</label>
    <select name="chastota" class="form-control linked__data">
      <option value="" selected>Выберите</option>
      <option value="1,5">1,5</option>
      <option value="2,7">2,7</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>ram</label>
    <select name="ram" class="form-control linked__data">
      <option value="" selected>Выберите</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>os</label>
    <select name="os" class="form-control linked__data">
      <option value="" selected>Выберите</option>
      <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
      <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<h1 id="count"></h1>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```